# Is it possible to calculate pressure without a barometer?

Tags: experimental-physics, pressure, ideal-gas

For an experiment, I need to pump air into a rocket with varying volumes of water, and thus air. However, I want to keep the pressure the same. Given the amount of air a bicycle pump can pump, the volume of air already in the rocket, and the desired pressure, is it possible to calculate how many pumps I need to achieve a certain pressure without a barometer.

One method I can think of is using the ideal (PV=nRT) and doing a string of calculations. This would involve using the universal molar volume of a gas (22.4 L/mol) to find how many moles of air are already there and how much more I need.

Comment: Install a relief valve in your discharge line, and stop pumping when the relief valve starts venting.

Comment: or install an air pressure gauge in the pressure hose from the pump, or use trial and error methods